# Getting element by id in DOM

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, polymer-2.x

I'm creating an [element](https://www.predix-ui.com/#/elements/px-modal) and then want to add an event listener to it. I'm doing:

```
console.log('about to create modal');
this.createModal(
  'There are unsubmitted changes in this Access Request.',
  'Do you wish to discard them?',
  'Yes',
  'No',
  'tabCloseModal'
);
console.log('created modal');
const modal = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#tabCloseModal');
console.log(`modal = ${modal}`);
modal.addEventListener('px-modal-accepted', function(e) {
  console.log('removing tab');
  this.removeTab(index);
});
```

Where `createModal` creates an element:

```
  createModal(headerText, bodyText, acceptText, rejectText, id, opened = true) {
    const modal = document.createElement('px-modal');
    //assign parameters
    document.swQuerySelector('body').appendChild(modal);
    console.log('Child appended');
    modal.visible = true;
    this.fire('modal-visible');
  }
```

No matter what I do (I tired `swQuerySelector`, `swQuerySelectorAll`, `querySelector`, `querySelectorAll`), I can't seem to get a hold of the modal. When I log it it just shows up as either empty, undefined or [object Object] or something like that, and I never get to 'removing tab'. What am I missing? The modal is showing up, but the mapping of the accepted event listener does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this:

1. Return the modal from `createModal`, and confirm it works as expected in the calling code.
2. If it does, the problem is in your `this.shadowRoot.querySelector` line.  Set a breakpoint at that point and try some paths to `querySelector` in the devtools `command line` until you get your modal.  Try to find the modal in your devtools `elements` window to see where it lies.  Without seeing a layout of your DOM, we cannot suggest the the exact path to the parent element.

The Shadow DOM can get 'shady' at times...

Comment: Even if I do `const modal = this.createModal('There are unsubmitted changes in this Access Request.', 'Do you wish to discard them?', 'Yes', 'No', 'tabCloseModal');` I still get `model = undefinded` on the console... No idea why. The modal does show up...

Comment: That's why step 1 was to figure out that out.  Before we proceed, did you return the modal from your function? `return modal;`